# ng-xi18n doesn't update all components when language changes

Tags: angular, internationalization

I'm playing around with the `ng-xi18n` library and it's been good so far. I'm loading in two languages: english and korean.

When I attempt to switch between the two, the language updates for my `login.component` only.

I have a `header.component` and a `footer.component` which uses the translations but they don't update. Why?

Code that changes the language:

```
<div class="container">
  <mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="over" [(opened)]="opened">
      Menu items
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
      <app-header [(opened)]="opened"></app-header>
      <div id="wrap">
        <app-login></app-login>
        <app-footer></app-footer>
      </div>
      <div id="languages" class="row">
        <a href="#" class="col" (click)="translate.use('en')">en</a>
        <a href="#" class="col" (click)="translate.use('kr')">kr</a>
      </div>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

The translations files:

**en.json**

```
{
  "HEADER": {},
  "LOGIN": {
    "TITLE": "Login",
    "USERNAME": "Username or email address",
    "PASSWORD": "Password",
    "LOST": "Lost your password?",
    "REMEMBER": "Remember Me"
  },
  "FOOTER": {
    "JOIN": "Join Our Newsletter",
    "MESSAGE": "...",
    "EMAIL": "Your email",
    "SUBSCRIBE": "Subscribe",
    "SHOP": "Shop Now",
    "ABOUT": "About us",
    "SCIENCE": "The Science",
    "FAQS": "FAQ's",
    "CONTACT": "Contact Us",
    "BLOG": "Blog",
    "SALE": "Conditions of Sale",
    "USE": "Conditions of Use",
    "PRIVACY": "Privacy Policy"
  }
}
```

**kr.json**

```
{
  "HEADER": {},
  "LOGIN": {
    "TITLE": "로그인",
    "USERNAME": "아이디 또는 이메일 주소",
    "PASSWORD": "암호",
    "LOST": "비밀번호를 잊어 버렸습니까?",
    "REMEMBER": "날 기억해"
  },
  "FOOTER": {
    "JOIN": "뉴스 레터 가입",
    "MESSAGE": "...",
    "EMAIL": "귀하의 이메일",
    "SUBSCRIBE": "구독하기",
    "SHOP": "지금 쇼핑하십시오",
    "ABOUT": "회사 소개",
    "SCIENCE": "과학",
    "FAQS": "FAQ's",
    "CONTACT": "연락처",
    "BLOG": "블로그",
    "SALE": "판매 조건",
    "USE": "이용 약관",
    "PRIVACY": "개인 정보 정책"
  }
}
```

I thought this was a caching issue in that because I was serving things from the assets folder the browser was using an old version of the file, but clearing the history doesn't do anything.

Also, for some reason only the korean version of the languages are loading on the footer!

Thanks

Comment: This does seem to be a caching issue. I just closed the window and reopened it. Suggests that it reloaded the cache for korean and english...

Comment: Could you please show how you are using the translations in the template or/and in the .ts file?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you are using the translations.

For example, if you are using them in the template file with the translate pipe, then this should be automatic.

However, if you are getting the translation in the typescript file (component), then you will need to listen to onLangChange EventEmitter which can be found by providing the TranslateService. Here you will have to re-write the logic to call the translations.

This information can be found in the API section here: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core

If you are doing all these things, then it may be contextual to what you are doing. In that case we will need some more information, as requested :)